# Parsing source fields in a SearchResult

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
    "hits": {
        "total": 4,
        "max_score": 12.914036,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "cars",
                "_type": "sports",
                "_id": "359809062-169200612195",
                "_score": 12.914036,
                "_source": {
                    "uniqueId": "35980",
                    "productName": "Tesla",
                    "Year": "2008"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "cars",
                "_type": "sports",
                "_id": "359809061-169200612191",
                "_score": 11.914036,
                "_source": {
                    "uniqueId": "33980",
                    "productName": "Ferrari",
                    "Year": "2015"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How to parse all the _source fields? Trying to return a list which contain only the _source fields in the hits.

```
val searchHits = searchResult.getHits(classOf[Object]).toList

searchHits.map(hit => {

        CarDetails(
          hit.source.get("uniqueId").getAsString(),
          hit.source.get("productName").getAsString(),
          hit.source.get("productName").getAsString(),

      })
    }
```

For this code, i get the error: value get is not a member of Object which is kind of expected.

Trying to parse the result without defining a model. Possible? 
I'm Jest Client with Scala.

**Context:**
CarDetails is a case class. Basically, what i'm trying to do is parse the hits (only the items inside _source) and return a list of CarDetails objects to the method that calls this function.

Comment: may i know what language your are using?

Comment: I'm using Scala

Comment: try searchResult.getHits().getHits(classOf[Object]).toList

Comment: `error: overloaded method value getHits with alternatives:
[scalac-2.10]   [T, K](x$1: Class[T], x$2: Class[K])java.util.List[io.searchbox.core.SearchResult#Hit[T,K]] <and>
[scalac-2.10]   [T](x$1: Class[T])java.util.List[io.searchbox.core.SearchResult#Hit[T,Void]]
[scalac-2.10]  cannot be applied to ()
[scalac-2.10]       val searchHits = searchResult.getHits().getHits(classOf[Object]).toList`

Comment: what client are you using?

Comment: Using Jest Client with Scala.

Comment: could you provide me the whole context.. so i that i can reproduce?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145861/discussion-between-nithin-chandy-and-blackpop).